# What happens to the energy of the photon in the red shift?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, redshift

In Doppler or Hubble red shift, the wavelength reached us is longer than the original wavelength, as a result, according to the Planck relation, its energy has decreased.
 Where does this energy go? Isn't this against the law of conservation of energy?
The idea that I have for this question is that energy is a geometric object, and the energy that we measure through the Planck relation equation is just the representation of that geometric object by our basis vectors, and these basis vectors change due expansion of the universe, this energy does not go anywhere, only its representation is changed by our basis vectors. Is this true?

Comment: For what it's worth, the (correct) answer in the "duplicate question" is mostly going down a tangent. The core of this question would remain in a flat static universe without gravity. Because even here, light sources moving apart appear redshifted with respect to each other.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Yes, definitely, in a world assuming the existence of gravity, the major part of the red shift will be due to Gravitational redshift. In this question, I just want to assume that there is an observer on one side of the world and an observer on the other side. The beam sent from the first observer to the observer Second, it is not affected by any gravitational waves and its energy should not have changed, but why is it not like this